# Vibration coupling through clothes as function of frequency

Tags: vibration, wearable

Serious question. Trying to figure out if there is any research/guidelines on selecting the frequency of a vibrator for a portable electronic device. This is safety related wearble device for first responders/cops/etc. I know lower frequency is better but is there a frequency that really starts to fall off when it comes to coupling vibrations though a belt or jacket/vest?

I've googled around a bit but all I'm finding is things related to measureing vibrations from heavy machinery and such.

Also, maybe this is more of a biology question?

Comment: Can't you just take the one some major cellphone manufacturers are setting? They have done this research for you already.

Comment: Personally cell phone vibration motors all suck these days. Haven't thought they were very useful for silently telling me there is a call/message/etc in years. I think this is mostly due to space constraints.

Comment: And what I'm looking for is something that you would want to alert you while you were in a burning building for example.

Answer (score 2):

Haptic feedback actuators are more common now with both linear resonant actuators (magnetic spring mass) as well as eccentric rotating mass vibration motors.

Linear actuators are most efficient and reliable but with lowest strength in mobiles but allow distinct feedback amplitude bursts.

Essentric Rotating mass vibrating motors increase linear frequency with voltage but impact is quadratic with rotational energy and fixed displacement, but heat energy limits frequency of small motors.

There is much more written about vibration isolation methods than actuators thru protection vests.

Old pagers used larger essentric mass vibrating motors but were less reliable, but in this case more detectable.

The frequency response of a bulletproof vest depends on the type, and tension or coupling mount of actuator, but is basically a low pass filter with weak coupling if loose for a small displacement actuator.

Comment: I'm aware of all this, what I'm after is guidlines for **what frequency** to use.  I'm expecting to use an essentric mass type but there are a lot of of options when it comes to RPM of the motor (vibation frequnecy). Obviously size/power come into play but in my application they are somewhat flexible.